# 12-5. Sideways Shooter - Python Crash Course

Tags: python, pygame

How do I alter my existing code to place a ship not on the bottom of the screen but on the left side of the screen, while still allowing the player to move the ship up and down.  The ship still needs to be able to fire but the bullet needs to travel right across the screen rather than upwards since the ship is no longer on the bottom of the screen.  Also, I need to make sure that the bullets are deleted once they disappear off of the screen.  Here is the code that I have.

Alien Invasion 5.py
    import pygame

```
from pygame.sprite import Group
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

  # Make a ship.
    ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
  # Make a group to store bullets in.
    bullets = Group()

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(bullets)
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

run_game()
```

---

game_functions.py

```
import sys

import pygame
from bullet import Bullet

def check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)


def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Fire a bullet if limit not reached yet."""
    # Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group.
    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet) 


def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    """Respond to key releases."""
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False                

def check_events(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Respond to keypresses and mouse events."""
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events(event, ship)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    """Update images on the screen and flip to the new screen."""
    # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    # Redraw all bullets behind the ship and aliens.
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.blitme()

def update_bullets(bullets):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
    # Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()

    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <=0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)  

    # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

settings.py

class Settings():
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

```
def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the game's settings."""
    # Screen settings
    self.screen_width = 1200
    self.screen_height = 800
    self.bg_color = (230,230,230)

    # Ship settings
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5

    # Bullet settings
    self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
    self.bullet_width = 3
    self.bullet_height = 15
    self.bullet_color = 60,60,60
    self.bullets_allowed = 3
```

---

bullet.py

import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired fromt he ship"""

```
def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position."""
    super(Bullet, self).__init__()
    self.screen = screen

    # Create a bullet rect at (0,0) and then set correct position.
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0,0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
        ai_settings.bullet_height)
    self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
    self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

    # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value.
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
    self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

def update(self):
    """Move the bullet up the screen."""
    # Update the decimal position of the bullet.
    self.y -= self.speed_factor
    # Update the rect position.
    self.rect.y = self.y

def draw_bullet(self):
    """Draw the bullet to the screen."""
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Comment: There is way too much code here for people to look through. The logic of your game is on your shoulders, I'm afraid. Questions here should focus on specific issues you face.

Comment: Please also read **[mcve]**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following better demonstrates the bullet class used to sole Problem 12- 5 of the "Python Crash Course".

```
import pygame

# The name used to create the .py where settings are stored 

from problem123settings import Settings   

ai_settings = Settings()

# Allow the grouping of related elements of the game and act on all the 
# grouped elements of the game at once with Sprite.

from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired from the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
        """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position."""

        # Super is called to inherit properly from Sprite.
        super().__init__()

        self.screen = screen

        # Create a bullet rect at  (0, 0) [x and y coordinates at the top left
        # corner of the screen] and then set the correct position.

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width,
        ai_settings.bullet_height)

        # Set bullet's centerx at the center of the ship.

        self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx

        # Set the bullet height at the center of the ship, therefore
        # making it appear that the bullet comes from the front of the ship.

        self.rect.center = ship.rect.center

        # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value.

        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
        self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor


    def update(self):       
        """Move the bullet across the screen."""

        '''
        The update() method manages the bullets position.  When a bullet is 
        fired, it moves across the screen, which corresponds to an increasing
        x-coordinate value; so to update the position, we add the amount 
        stored in self.speed_factor to self.x.  We then use the value of
        self.x to set the value of self.rect.x.  Once fired the bullets
        y-coordinate value never changes.

        ''' 
        self.x += self.speed_factor


        # Update the rect position of the bullet.

        self.rect.x = self.x


    def draw_bullet(self):
        """Draw the bullet to the screen."""

        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def update_bullets(bullets):
    """Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets."""
    # Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()

    # Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <=0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
```

You will have to insert another parameter ai_settings to make sure when the bullet crosses the width of the screen its removed.
Try this and it should work:

```
def update_bullets(bullets,ai_settings):

    """Update the position of bullets and get rid of the old bullets."""
    #Update bullet positions.
    bullets.update()
    ai_settings = Settings()

    #Get rid of bullets that have disappeared.

    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.x >ai_settings.screen_width:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
```